# Install Oracle Database 19c on CentOS 8 - oraInstall<timestamp>.out(Permission denied)

Tags: oracle, permissions, centos

I am following the instructions "How to Install Oracle Database 19c on CentOS 8".

Link: https://manjaro.site/how-to-install-oracle-database-19c-on-centos-8/

I login as oracle and start the runInstaller. The installation Wizard starts and everything works until I click on install where the following error occurs:

**/u01/app/oracle/product/19.0.0/dbhome_1/Inventory/Scripts/oraInstall.out(Permission denied).**

[Snapshot error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cEPnq.png)

I changed owner and permissions as instructed:

```
chown -R oracle:oinstall /u01 /u02 
chmod -R 775 /u01 /u02

chown -R oracle:oinstall /home/oracle/scripts 
chmod u+x /home/oracle/scripts/*.sh
```

Would be really nice if somebody could help me solve this issue.

Many thanks.

Best

S.

Comment: Instead of getting your installation "instructions" from some hinky, ad-festooned blog, why not use the _official_ installation guide?  See https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/ladbi/index.html

Comment: Well, I was instructed to follow this instruction. I definitely agree that following the official installation guide is the proper way to do it but I think these instructions exist because they brake down the extensive information. And it actually worked in the end. **I missed one option in the window before, where you can select the group with writing permission in the respective location**. I hope I find time in the future to follow the official instructions and actually learn something!

Comment: " I was instructed to follow this instruction."  And who 'instructed' you to do that?  Is this from a class you are taking?  I'd have serious reservations about anyone who would give such "instructions".

Comment: Hi Ed, "instructed to follow" was maybe the wrong implication. I asked around if someone had done this before and the person was so kind to provide me with his personal notes. So I am rather grateful that it was provided and it was solely my choice in the end to follow it. So I think this is rather on me.

Answer (score 0):

Update

So, as stated above, I just missed an option in the window of the Installation Wizard before the "Error" occured.

I had to select the group with writing permissions in the specified location. After that the installation went through.

Here again, I agree to Ed that following the official instructions would have been the proper way to do it!